# How to keep US-English locale while using an Italian (or French) keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, microsoft-powerpoint, locale

I have a very basic Win7 usage problem:

My PC has an Italian keyboard, but I need to work with an US-English environment (Win7 is in English).

Problem is in many programs (most notably in PowerPoint) system defaults to Italian settings (including dictionary checking) and I have to change them every time. This is particularly nasty in Power Point because I have to change Language in each TextBox I create.

Need is to work with a full US-English Locale but to have a different Keyboard. I was unable to find the right setting (and the fact the laptop is actually French and Power Point templates I need to use come from Germany add confusion to chaos). Language bar seems to govern keyboard together all other Locale settings (which usually makes sense, of course). How can I separate them?

Here are screenshots of relevant panels, as requested:

[image: Region and Language] --- [image: Text Services and Input Languages]

**NOTE:** strange thing is everything seems to work as expected today, even if I do not recall changing anything since yesterday. Did the system need a restart to actualize settings? Anyways problem seems solved. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: What are your settings in Region and Language control panel? All should be default for English Windows, except for in Keyboards and Languages/Change keyboards set the keyboard type (and I assume you would set that to default (top) position). Only keyboard entry based on your keyboard should be changed. And the "Formats" tab need to be set to default English settings. You might add some relevant screenshots from these control panel tabs. Also what other apps are affected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following.

1. System Locale should set to English.

   [image: Language for non-Unocide apps]
2. Set Format to en-us. Some apps check this as well.

   [image: Formats]

In addition, I don't think the IME (keyboard) settings affect on the symptoms you are undergoing.